# Can .htacces file really protect internal pages from public access?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, privacy

Is there some way to directly access pages in mydomain.com, e.g. mydomain.com/secretpage.php, when .htaccess file redirect all requests to index.php? Or, in other words, are the pages under mydomain.com protected against public access if I have a rule in the .htaccess file that redirect all requests to index.php?

My .htacces looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

... and yes, I have no previous experience working with .htaccess files.

Comment: If secret.php is present, your rules will execute it, wont redirect to index.php. 2-3 lines say if file or directory is not present proceed with rewrite. If they are present they will be executed normally, without redirect

Comment: @Muhammed M. Is there some rule that tell to Apache allways redirect requests to index.php, even if, like in my example, secretpage.php is under mydomain.com?

Comment: How do you differentiate local traffic and public traffic?

Comment: just remove those php files from the root, there is no place for them there if you want redirection, as they shouldn't be accessible directly

Comment: @Muhammed M. I am just trying to avoid any type of access to all my files and folders under mydomain... if I remove secretpage.php from the root I still have to put that page in some place, e. g., mydir. What to do to prevent to show pages under mydir if a visitor insert www.mydomain.com/mydir in his/her browser address bar?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  \.(php)$ - you can use this to catch access to .php files

Comment: you can put the secret files in a directory ABOVE your public directory instead of a subdirectory ofpublic

Comment: @Nowdeen look at my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Keep you rewriterule but remove the condition that way index.php will ALWAYS be loaded.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to allow to execute any php files escept for index.php but you do want to allow access to other files such as jpg, css, js, etc. Use this, it will redirect all php files to index.php, but not other type of files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^(.*)\.php)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Using this rule I really do not have direct access from browser to files under mydomain.com, BUT my pages in mydomain.com stopped to load assets, such as js, css, img and so on...

Comment: so you don't want any php files to be accessible except for index.php?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more time you are right, I cant run php files in the first level of mydomain.com... BUT when I wrote mydomain.com/dir/file.php in my browser, the dream was over... file.php must not have direct access to visitors!